# Creating a Desktop Version of a Web Application (NextJS TypeScript Golang Echo)

Tags: postgresql, go, next.js, web-applications, windows-installer

I have created a website application using nextjs typescript for the frontend and golang echo for the backend with a postgresql database. How do I create the desktop version (.exe)? Is there a way that I can do to create a desktop version of my website application? especially for Windows installers, so users can install them on their respective desktops and don't need to be connected to the internet.